# Python3.8 Round with decimal Constructor with Float or String

Tags: python-3.x, decimal

I hit some strange behavior when dealing with python decimal module

Example below:

```
print(round(Decimal('0.005'),2))
>>> Decimal('0.00')
print(round(Decimal(0.005),2))
>>> Decimal('0.01')


print(round(Decimal('0.006'),2))
>>> Decimal('0.01')
print(round(Decimal(0.006),2))
>>> Decimal('0.01')
```

Can someone explain why is this happen and how can I convert `Decimal('0.005')` to `Decimal(0.005)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're noticing floating point representation of decimal digits

```
>>> Decimal(0.005) 
Decimal('0.005000000000000000104083408558608425664715468883514404296875')
```

is that equal to 0.005?

```
>>> 0.005 == 0.005000000000000000104083408558608425664715468883514404296875
True
```

In the rounding stage, since the value is > `0.005`, it rounds to `0.01`.

This is the expected behavior.

> how can I convert Decimal('0.005') to Decimal(0.005)

```
>>> round(Decimal(float('0.005')), 2)
Decimal('0.01')
```

However, that is probably not what you want. The appropriate thing to do, *it seems to me*, would be to convert your input faithfully to a decimal, and then apply a rounding strategy explicitly.

To convert your floating point input to a Decimal

There are a couple of options.

1. Apply `str` your input

   ```
   >>> Decimal(str(0.005)) == Decimal(str('0.005'))
   True
   ```
2. `quantize` after converting the float to decimal. quantize also allows you to round & specify the exact rounding method. Note that here, I'm not rounding with the quantize method (that example is further below). Here, I specify the same number of digits as the input.

   ```
   >>> Decimal(0.005).quantize(Decimal('1.000'))
   Decimal('0.005')
   ```

To round, you can call `round` on the `Decimal` object, as you have done. Or you can use the `Decimal.quantize` method

```
Decimal(0.005).quantize(Decimal('1.00'), rounding=<ROUNDING_METHOD>)
```

where the available `ROUNDING_METHOD` are found [in the documentation for the decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes)

If you want `Decimal(0.005)` to always be rounded up, then specify `ROUND_HALF_UP`. However, note that python 3's default rounding behavior is `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` (also called banker's rounding), and that is why `round(Decimal('0.005'), 2)` outputs `0.00`